# how to use google spreadsheet as login database in blogger?

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, blogger

I have database in spreadsheet like this

[image: database]

```js
var myTimer;

function clock() {
  myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
  var c = 10;
  var pass1 = 123;
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
 

    
  function myClock() {
    if (input == pass1) {
     document.getElementById( 'login' ).style.display = 'none'}}}
```

```html
<div  id="login">
    <center>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
  <input type="password" id="userInput" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="clock()" value="Start" id="popUpYes"/>
  <!---<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>--->
</form>
</center>
  </div>
```

How to connect with user and password in spreadheet? I'm sure that this code must be change. but how?

```
var pass1 = 123;
      var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

Comment: Hello, if you'd like to get data from a Google Spreadsheet, you need to write a Google Script function, follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_1_deploy_the_script_as_an_api_executable), and then call it from your javascript.

Comment: I have read it, but I'm not understand with the step

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get it. I am a beginner who uses blogger

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, go to *Tools* > *Script editor*. Add this function in the Apps Script editor:

```js
function getPass(user) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pwr = ss.getRange("SheetName!A1:B100"); //Put sheet (tab) name here
  for (var i = 0; i < pwr.getNumRows(); i++) {
    if (pwr.getCell(i, 1).getDisplayValue() == user) return pwr.getCell(i, 2).getDisplayValue();
  }
  return "No user found";
}
```

Go to *File* > *Manage Versions*, add a description, and press "*Save new version*".

Then, go to *Publish* > *Deploy as API executable*, select version 1 in the version drop-down, and choose who's allowed to edit the project. Press "*Deploy*", and copy the string underneath "*Current API ID*".

*(If these options aren't visible, you haven't switched to a GCP project. See [switching to a standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).)*

Go to the GCP project on the console, [enable Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#enabling_an_api_in_a_standard_gcp_project), [configure OAuth](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#completing_the_oauth_consent_screen), and [create credentials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#creating_oauth_credentials). Generate an OAuth token with the ID you copied, and the required scopes for your script (visible under *File* > *Project properties* > *Scopes*), and keep this secret.

Finally, setup a request in your javascript project with [this request body format](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run).

---

If all of this is a bit complicated, I know - security concerns make it quite difficult to make something. [This quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js) and [this JavaScript code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#javascript) might help.

Comment: User managed Cloud Platform project is required
You are using a Cloud Platform project managed by Apps Script. In order to publish, you must switch to a user-managed Cloud Platform project for this script.

I got that message while trying to Deploy as API executable

Comment: Yes, see [switching to a standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project), you need to do this to export anything with Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: thankyou for your help. But it is very hard for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

- You can create an [Apps Script WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that contains both serverside Apps Script code and client side html/Javascript code within the same project.
- Thereby, interfaces such as [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) and [Apps Script scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) allow the communication between the two parts.

### Sample

code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function logPassword(password) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");
  sheet.appendRow([password])
}
```

index.html:

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div  id="login">
    <center>
     <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      <input type="password" id="userInput" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" onclick="clock()" value="Start" id="popUpYes"/>
      <!---<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>--->
    </form>
   </center>
  </div>
  <script>
    ...
    function clock() {
      var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
      google.script.run.logPassword(input);
      ...
    }
    ...
   </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```